# Add data values to D3.js bar chart in the middle or above

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, charts

I am trying to add data labels to a d3.js bar chart. Each bar should have its data labels either in the middle or above.

For example, the first bar should have 730 displayed if its value is 730 and so on...

Like this:

[image]

Is that possible?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="../../d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
body {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 530px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.bar {
  fill: orange;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.myText {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 10px;
}

.slidecontainer {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  width: 50%; /* Full-width */
  height: 25px; /* Specified height */
  background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
  outline: none; /* Remove outline */
  opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}

/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4caf50; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4caf50; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    0 <input type="range" min="1" max="163" value="163" class="slider" id="sliderVal"> 163
    <p>Threshold Line Value: <span id="maxVal"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div id="graph"></div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("sliderVal");
var output = document.getElementById("maxVal");

function clearCanvas() {
  d3.select('svg').remove();
}

function drawGraph() { // this needs tidying up so you don't need to get data more than once!

    // Set the margins
  var margin = {top: 60, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80},
    width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Parse the month variable
  var parseMonth = d3.timeParse("%b");
  var formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

  // Set the ranges
  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1)
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  // Create the svg canvas in the "graph" div
  var svg = d3.select("#graph")
          .append("svg")
          .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
          .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .attr("class", "svg");

  // Import the CSV data
  d3.csv("../dataset_visits.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

     // Format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
        d.S40411 = +d.S40411;
        d.S40412 = +d.S40412;
        d.S40413 = +d.S40413;
        d.S40414 = +d.S40414;
    });

  var nest = [];//create empty array
  var keys = ['S40411','S40412','S40413','S40414']; //the headers for your data
  //for each header push the sum as an object
  keys.forEach(function (d, i) {
    //get the sumfrom your data for all the values of this key i.e. d
    var sum = d3.sum (data, function(e){ return e[d] }); 
    //create an object with this key value pair
    var obj = {
      key: d, //column name
      value: sum //sum for the column
    }
    nest.push(obj); //push this as an object in the nest array
  })

  console.log(nest)
    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(nest.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(nest, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    // check that 200% line will be within chart
    maxVal = +d3.select('#maxVal').text();
    if ( maxVal * 4.5 > y.domain()[1]) {
      y.domain([0,maxVal*4.5*1.1]);
    }

    // Set up the x axis
    var xaxis = svg.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .attr("class", "x axis")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
            //.ticks(d3.timeMonth)
            .tickSize(0, 0)
            //.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
            .tickSizeInner(0)
            .tickPadding(10));

    // Add the Y Axis
     var yaxis = svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis")
         .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSizeInner(0)
            .tickPadding(6)
            .tickSize(0, 0));

   // yaxis.select(".domain").style("display","none")

    // Add a label to the y axis
    svg.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 0 - 60)
          .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("Visits")
          .attr("class", "y axis label");

    // Draw the bars
    svg.selectAll(".rect")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

    // Three lines and labels for the thresholds 0%, 100%, 200% target achievement -->

    var thresholds = {
      v0: maxVal*3,
      v1: maxVal*4,
      v2: maxVal*4.5
    }
    console.log(thresholds);
    // Draw the line for the first threshold
    svg.append("line")
      .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v0))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v0));

    // Draw the label for the first threshold
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "myText")
      .attr("x", width + 2)
        .attr("y", y(thresholds.v0))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
        .text("0% ≈ " + thresholds.v0.toFixed(2));

    // Draw the line for the second threshold
    svg.append("line")
      .style("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v1))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v1));

    // Draw the label for the second threshold
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "myText")
      .attr("x", width + 2)
        .attr("y", y(thresholds.v1))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
        .text("100% ≈ " + thresholds.v1.toFixed(2));
    // Draw the line for the third threshold
    svg.append("line")
      .style("stroke", "green")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v2))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v2));

    // Draw the label for the third threshold
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "myText")
      .attr("x", width + 2)
        .attr("y", y(thresholds.v2))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
        .text("200% ≈ " + thresholds.v2.toFixed(2));

  })
}

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  clearCanvas();
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  drawGraph();
}

// initial call

output.innerHTML = slider.value;
drawGraph();
</script>

</body>
```

Each bar should display its value within the bar or above.

There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951630/add-labels-to-bar-in-d3-chart) that prentends so solve the same issue.
In their [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL2shzzw/) it works fine!

I am trying to adapt and insert this code, but it isn´t working:

```
var text = chart.selectAll(".text")
    .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("class","text");

var labels = text.attr("x", function (d) {
        return xScale(d.year) + xScale.rangeBand()/2;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {return yScale(d.tickets);})
    .text(function (d) { return d.tickets;});
```

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/robx360/pen/wvvRYzq)

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788524/d3-bar-chart-append-text-to-bar

Comment: http://www.cagrimmett.com/til/2016/04/26/responsive-d3-bar-chart.html

Comment: does not work. Tried almost everything

Comment: can you please add your code in fiddle then we can definitely help

Comment: Updated tyhe question. this is my codepen: https://codepen.io/robx360/pen/wvvRYzq

Comment: I added an answer for this display text issue in bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the text is added to the bar as you expected. please check and confirm

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("sliderVal");
var output = document.getElementById("maxVal");

function clearCanvas() {
  d3.select('svg').remove();
}

function drawGraph() { // this needs tidying up so you don't need to get data more than once!

    // Set the margins
  var margin = {top: 60, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 80},
    width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Parse the month variable
  var parseMonth = d3.timeParse("%b");
  var formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%b");

  // Set the ranges
  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1)
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  // Create the svg canvas in the "graph" div
  var svg = d3.select("#graph")
          .append("svg")
          .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
          .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .attr("class", "svg");

  // Import the CSV data
  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rob360/x1/master/dataset_visits.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

     // Format the data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Month = parseMonth(d.Month);
        d.S40401 = +d.S40401;
        d.S40402 = +d.S40402;
        d.S40403 = +d.S40403;
    });

  var nest = [];//create empty array
  var keys = ['S40401','S40402','S40403']; //the headers for your data
  //for each header push the sum as an object
  keys.forEach(function (d, i) {
    //get the sumfrom your data for all the values of this key i.e. d
    var sum = d3.sum (data, function(e){ return e[d] }); 
    //create an object with this key value pair
    var obj = {
      key: d, //column name
      value: sum //sum for the column
    }
    nest.push(obj); //push this as an object in the nest array
  })

  
    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(nest.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(nest, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    // check that 200% line will be within chart
    maxVal = +d3.select('#maxVal').text();
    if ( maxVal * 4.5 > y.domain()[1]) {
      y.domain([0,maxVal*4.5*1.1]);
    }

    // Set up the x axis
    var xaxis = svg.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .attr("class", "x axis")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
            //.ticks(d3.timeMonth)
            .tickSize(0, 0)
            //.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B"))
            .tickSizeInner(0)
            .tickPadding(10));

    // Add the Y Axis
     var yaxis = svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis")
         .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(5)
            .tickSizeInner(0)
            .tickPadding(6)
            .tickSize(0, 0));

    svg.append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 0 - 60)
          .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
          .attr("dy", "1em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("Visits")
          .attr("class", "y axis label");

    // Draw the bars
    svg.selectAll(".rect")
        .data(nest)
        .enter()        
     .append("text")
       .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key) +3; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (y(d.value)) ; }) // Center text
            .attr("dy", "1em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
    
    
    svg.selectAll(".rect")
        .data(nest)
        .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { console.log(d); return x(d.key); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      
   
    
        
          var thresholds = {
      v0: maxVal*3,
      v1: maxVal*4,
      v2: maxVal*4.5
    }
    console.log(thresholds);
    // Draw the line for the first threshold
    svg.append("line")
      .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v0))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v0));

    // Draw the label for the first threshold
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "myText")
      .attr("x", width + 2)
        .attr("y", y(thresholds.v0))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
        .text("0% ≈ " + thresholds.v0.toFixed(2));

    // Draw the line for the second threshold
    svg.append("line")
      .style("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v1))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v1));

    // Draw the label for the second threshold
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "myText")
      .attr("x", width + 2)
        .attr("y", y(thresholds.v1))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
        .text("100% ≈ " + thresholds.v1.toFixed(2));
    // Draw the line for the third threshold
    svg.append("line")
      .style("stroke", "green")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(thresholds.v2))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(thresholds.v2));

    // Draw the label for the third threshold
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "myText")
      .attr("x", width + 2)
        .attr("y", y(thresholds.v2))
        .attr("dominant-baseline", "ideographic")
        .text("200% ≈ " + thresholds.v2.toFixed(2));
    
           

  })
}

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
  clearCanvas();
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  drawGraph();
}

// initial call

output.innerHTML = slider.value;
drawGraph();
```

```css
text {
  font-size: 12px;
  fill: #000;
}


text.value {
  font-size: 14px;
}

text.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

text.label {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

text.source {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
body {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 530px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.bar {
  fill: orange;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.myText {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 10px;
}

.slidecontainer {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  width: 50%; /* Full-width */
  height: 25px; /* Specified height */
  background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
  outline: none; /* Remove outline */
  opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}

/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4caf50; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4caf50; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    0 <input type="range" min="1" max="163" value="163" class="slider" id="sliderVal"> 163
    <p>Threshold Line Value: <span id="maxVal"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
 

</body>
```

Comment: Please check this https://codepen.io/jayakumar/pen/YzzBgKN I have spent more time to solve this issue